# Quartz.NET - no configuration section <common/logging> found - suppressing logging output

Tags: log4net, quartz.net

I am trying to use **Quartz 2.1.2** with logging, but I keep getting the following output when I debug:

> no configuration section  found - suppressing logging
>   output

Here is my **App.config** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="common">
      <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging" />
 </sectionGroup>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <common>
    <logging>
      <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.Log4Net">
        <arg key="configType" value="INLINE"/>
        <arg key="configFile" value="c:\Scheduler.log"/>
        <arg key="level" value="INFO" />
      </factoryAdapter>
    </logging>
  </common>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%d [%t] %-5p %l - %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="INFO" />
      <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

And here is the code for instantiating my Scheduler:

```
private IScheduler scheduler;

    public JobScheduler()
    {
        ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        this.scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
        this.scheduler.Start();
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

Okay, so one thing I was doing wrong was not including the App.config file in my unit test project.  Once I did that, I got a different error:

> Unable to create type 'Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.Log4Net'

I didn't see Log4Net in the Common.Logging namespace so I added the DLL via Package Manager, but I still get the same error.  I am using Common.Logging version 2.1.2.  Any ideas why I am still having an issue?

Comment: If you are getting the 'unable to create type' exception, it should also contain inner exceptions which contain more details on why it can't create the type.

Answer (score 3):

first of all check that you have all the packages (assemblies) updates.
This is my **nuget** packages.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Common.Logging" version="2.1.2" targetFramework="net35" />
  <package id="Common.Logging.Log4Net" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="log4net" version="1.2.10" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Quartz" version="2.1.2" targetFramework="net35" />
</packages>
```

I reckon that you have to force-update `Common.Logging.Log4Net` cause Quartz.net doesn't download the latest version.

Then check your **App.config**. You should have this binding:

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Common.Logging" publicKeyToken="af08829b84f0328e" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.2.0" newVersion="2.1.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

I think you're using the wrong appender. You seem you want to write your log in a file but you're using **EventLogAppender**.

If you want to use file system you can try with this config sections:

```
  <common>
    <logging>
      <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.Log4Net">
        <arg key="configType" value="INLINE" />
        <arg key="level" value="INFO" />
      </factoryAdapter>
    </logging>
  </common>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="c:\Scheduler.log" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss} – %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="INFO" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

You might have problems with permissions trying to write in that folder. If you want to put your logs in the bin folder if your app change this:

```
<param name="File" value="Scheduler.log" />
```

Comment: Subsequent to this answer being posted, the Common.Logging.Log4Net package has been changed to use a different package to access each Log4Net version and each different package version uses a different assembly name.  So, to get the factoryAdapter config above to work, you must include the version number on the assembly name.  So, for example if you are using Common.Logging.Log4Net1213, you'll need to have this in the config: <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.Log4Net1213">

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the Common.Logging library in the same folder as your Quartz library (C5 should also be there). As far as I know, you don't have to reference it from within Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the [Common.Logging.Log4Net1211](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Common.Logging.Log4Net1211/) and change the appsetting as following

```
  <common>
    <logging>
      <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.Log4Net1211">
        <arg key="configType" value="INLINE"/>
      </factoryAdapter>
    </logging>
  </common>
```

Note that dll name changed to "Common.Logging.Log4Net1211".